# What is this weed with purple flowers?

Tags: identification, weeds

my garden is full of these plants (weeds) and I'm wondering what are they.

The purple flower (small bit that attaches to the plant) is a bit sweet in taste.

Location: Moldova (Eastern Europe), it grows in summer time.

Pictures taken at the beginning of July.

[image: pitcure1]

[image: pitcure2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its Ballota nigra; its common name in the UK is Black Horehound, so called because it was once recommended as a herbal treatment for people who'd been bitten by mad dogs. Native to the mediterranean and central Asia, but can be found throughout Europe and parts of the USA. For images and information see here http://www.naturalmedicinefacts.info/plant/ballota-nigra.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Bamboo in England has different names...but this looks like HENBIT.  Lamium amplexicaule.  [Lamium amplexicaule or Henbit](http://www.ediblewildfood.com/henbit.aspx)  If you gotta have a weed this is a cool plant.  Dandelions and Henbit are totally edible and you could live off these two plants, for a long time. I'll go check out Bamboo's link.  She is so rarely wrong that no one can remember those instances...!!

Well shoot.  Same family; Lamiaceae...I think the difference is in the petioles or the 'stems' that support the leaves...one has them the other does not.  Could you send a picture of a closeup of the leaves and stem of these plants?

Comment: Please be careful 'tasting' anything in the plant world until we can ID it for you.  Grins...

Comment: I checked out all the henbits, but black horehound was most like the plant in the photo, the foliage/leaf shape in particular - we do use the term henbit for L amplexicaule

Comment: So these are two different plants?  Did you see the bit about the petioles of the leaves?  One has them the other does not.  Way cool Bamboo!

Comment: I've seen the Henbit as well in the garden, but in the picture, after googling images, it looks like it's "Ballot Nigra"